# C++ Incrementing Not Working in If Else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, increment

I'm trying to create a program that allows a user to input the scores given by five judges. However, once it gets to the third judge's score, the incrementing used to label the judge # stops working, and I believe it has to do with it being in an if/else statement. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string name;
string city;
double highestScore;
double lowestScore;
double totalScore;

void main()
{

    cout << "   Report to the media" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the diver name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the diver's city: ";
    getline(cin, city);
    cout << endl;

    int count = 0;
    double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;
    int judgeNum = 0;

    judgeNum ++;
    cout << "Enter the score given by judge #" << judgeNum << ": ";
    cin >> score1;
    if (score1 < 0 || score1 > 10)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                cin >> score1;
            }
    cout << endl; 
    count ++;

    while (count <= 5)
    {
        judgeNum ++;
        count ++;

        cout << "Enter the score given by judge #" << judgeNum << ": ";

        if (judgeNum = 2)
        {
            cin >> score2;
            if (score2 < 0 || score2 > 10)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                cin >> score2;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (judgeNum = 3)
            {
                cin >> score3;
                if (score3 < 0 || score3 > 10)
                {
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                    cin >> score3;
                }               
            }
            else 
            {
                if (judgeNum = 4)
                {
                    cin >> score4;
                    if (score4 < 0 || score4 > 10)
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                        cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                        cin >> score4;
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (judgeNum = 5)
                    {
                        cin >> score5;
                        if (score5 < 0 || score5 > 10)
                        {
                            cout << endl;
                            cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                            cin >> score5;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << score1 << score2 << score3 << score4 << score5;
}
```

Comment: Remove all code not necessary to replicate the error. Also, tell us what input caused the error, what output you got, and what output you expected.

Comment: `if(judgeNum = 1)` looks very odd to me. `=` and `==` are two different things in C++. When you want to assign a value to a variable, use `=` and when you are comparing two things, use `==`.

Comment: See your code carefully.

Comment: you have judge++ in main (so it's 1)
then you have judge++ in a loop (so it's 2) (then you make it 2 as @kdmurray91 says)

Comment: Whenever your code looks like someone did a bunch of cutting and pasting, that should be an indication that you're doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I once managed to make a custom string allocator from 3 SO answers, but I knew what I wanted and it took about a day to understand some parts of it. I love C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (judgeNum = 2)` sets judgeNum to 2, and then checks if the new value of judgeNum is "truthy" (non-zero). Since the new value is 2, it always will be, and judgeNum will always be set to 2 here, then incremented.

In C, C++ and most other langages, equality is determined using two `=`s, like `if (judgeNum == 2)`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: Thanks, pretty embarrassing mistake honestly, I knew that but totally messed that up.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [kdmurray91's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42895866/4544967)

Correct One

```
using namespace std;

string name;
string city;
double highestScore;
double lowestScore;
double totalScore;

void main()
{

    cout << "   Report to the media" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the diver name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the diver's city: ";
    getline(cin, city);
    cout << endl;

    int count = 0;
    double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;
    int judgeNum = 0;

    judgeNum ++;
    cout << "Enter the score given by judge #" << judgeNum << ": ";
    cin >> score1;
    if (score1 < 0 || score1 > 10)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                cin >> score1;
            }
    cout << endl; 
    count ++;

    while (count <= 5)
    {
        judgeNum ++;
        count ++;

        cout << "Enter the score given by judge #" << judgeNum << ": ";

        if (judgeNum == 2)
        {
            cin >> score2;
            if (score2 < 0 || score2 > 10)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                cin >> score2;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (judgeNum == 3)
            {
                cin >> score3;
                if (score3 < 0 || score3 > 10)
                {
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                    cin >> score3;
                }               
            }
            else 
            {
                if (judgeNum == 4)
                {
                    cin >> score4;
                    if (score4 < 0 || score4 > 10)
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                        cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                        cin >> score4;
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (judgeNum == 5)
                    {
                        cin >> score5;
                        if (score5 < 0 || score5 > 10)
                        {
                            cout << endl;
                            cout << "Score must be between 1 and 10. Please re-enter score: ";
                            cin >> score5;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << score1 << score2 << score3 << score4 << score5;
}
```